# Separation of Concerns: Returning Projected Data between layers From a Linq Query

Tags: linq, projection, separation-of-concerns, return-type

I'm using Linq and having trouble doing something that I believe should be trivial. I want to return data from one layer so it can be used independently of linq in another layer.

Suppose I have a Data Access Layer.  It knows about the entity framework and how to interact with it.  But, it doesn't care who accesses it.  The one interesting requirement I have is that the queries in the entity framework return projected data that is not part of the Entity Model itself.  *Please don't ask me to change this part of the requirement and make POCOs for each return type, as it is not the best design given the problem I am trying to solve.*  Below is an example.

```
public class ChartData
{
    public function <<returnType??>> GetData()
    {
        MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
        var results = from context.vManyColumnsOfData as v
                      where v.CompanyName = "acme"
                      select new {Year = v.SalesYear, Income = v.Income};
        return ??;
    }
}
```

Then, I would like to have an ASP.Net UI layer be able to call into the Data Access Layer to get the data in order to bind it to a control.  The UI layer should have no notion of where the data came from.  It should only know that it has the data it needs to bind.  Below is an example.

```
    protected void chart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // set some chart properties
       chart.Skin = "Default";
       ...

       // Set the data source
       ChartData dataMgr = new ChartData();
       <<returnType?>> data = dataMgr.GetData();
       chart.DataSource = data;
       chart.DataBind();
    }
```

What is the best way to send linq projected data back to another layer?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use the projected type statically, just return `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Sounds like I'm at least getting some agreement on the approach.

Answer (score 2):

> Please don't ask me to change this part of the requirement and make
>   POCOs for each return type, as it is not the best design given the
>   problem I am trying to solve.

I feel like I should rightly ignore this, as the best thing to do *is* to return a defined type. Anonymous types are useful when they are wholly contained within the method that creates them. Once you start passing them around, it is time to go ahead and give them the proper class treatment.

However, to live within your imposed limitations, you can return `IEnumerable<object>` from the method and use that or `var` at the callsite and rely upon the dynamic binding of the control to get at the data. It's not going to help *you* if you need to deal with the object programmatically, but it will serve fine for databinding.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return an anonymous type, so basically for this you will need POCO's even though you don't want them.

**"not the best design given the problem I am trying to solve"**

Could you explain what you are trying to achieve a little more? It might be possible to return some type of list containing a dictionary of items (ie rows and columns). Think something like an untyped dataset (yuck)

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetData` method can use [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) (the "old" non-generic interface) as its return type.

Any dynamic resolution (e.g. ASP.NET or XAML bindings) should work as expected, which seems to be what you want to do.

However, if you want to use the results in your code, you will probably have to resort to .NET 4's `dynamic` keyword.

The following example can be run in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (in "C# Program" mode) and illustrates this:

```
void Main()
{
  var v = GetData();

  foreach (dynamic element in v)
  {
    ((string)element.Name).Dump();
  }
}

public IEnumerable GetData()
{
  return from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
         select new
         {
              Name = "Item " + i,
              Value = i
         };
}
```

Keep in mind that, design-wise, coding like this will make most people frown and can affect performance.

Comment: Very interesting ... I did not know about the dynamic keyword. I can easily see the performance limitations. Incidently, I will not be using the results in code (or I would have gone for the POCO, though it would have resulted in a tight coupling I wanted to avoid.)  But, thanks for the pattern.

Comment: @ItsAllABadJoke, `dynamic` is certainly something that could be used, but keep in mind that under the covers, `dynamic` is just `object`, and it causes the compiler to start up during runtime and perform the same analysis it would if it had the proper information at compile time. It's more or less a form of reflection, but it least it can be cheaper over the aggregate.

Comment: The other thing is that it basically says "the method returning the data knows what's in there, the method receiving the data knows what's in there, but yet somehow I didn't bother to document what's in there and make it easy to use." `dynamic` has its place, certainly useful for interacting with external APIs, but in this case? If you were to decide you needed programmatic access, again, define a class.